# Full Calendar external event add class on ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar for a project. I want to show a tick mark such as (✓) using a css class when the external event dropped to calendar gets updated to the database.

The drop function is working perfectly. Here is my function:

```
drop: function(date) {
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
        var copiedEventObject   = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { 
            id: copiedEventObject.id,
            task: {
              start_date: date,
              dropped: true
            }
          },
          url: "/tasks/ajax_update"
        }).done(function() {
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents");
          $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");

          //Problem here (not sure how to get the updated event to add a class)
          copiedEventObject.className = "fc-updated";   //Tried this but Not working
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', copiedEventObject);  //Tried this but Not working
        });
}
```

When the event gets updated to the database, I am not able to get the exact event which has been updated. Is there a way to identify the updated event and add a css class using jQuery to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really need to `removeEvents` and then `refetchEvents` ? Can use `eventRender` callback to check for `className` and apply to `element`

Comment: No removeEvents and refetchEvents are not necessary. They are just to show the updated events. How can I use eventRender callback? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: within callback ... `if(event.className){ element.addClass(event.className) }`

Comment: Thanks for the code charlietfl, but I am not sure how it works inside the ajax done() function. eventRender callback works when the events are being rendered, not when the event is updated.

Comment: but `update` has to be original object, not a reconstructed one as you are doing. See update docs

Comment: There may be more than one instance of external event that is dropped, so I cannot use original object. I have to make copies of it. Does it makes any difference?